# Pytest fixtures skipping test

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django, pytest-fixtures

I have this factory as ficture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def user_factory(db):
    def create_app_user(
            username: str,
            password: str = None,
            first_name: str = "firstname",
            last_name: str = "lastname",
            email: str = "user@g.com",
            is_staff: str = False,
            is_superuser: str = False,
            is_active: str = True
    ):
        user_f = User.objects.create_user(
            username = username,
            password = password,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            email = email,
            is_staff = is_staff,
            is_superuser = is_superuser,
            is_active = is_active
        )
        return user_f
    return create_app_user


@pytest.fixture
def new_user(db, user_factory):
    return user_factory("myusername", "mypassword", "myfirstname")
```

I tried to use the factory to run this test which is located in test_name.py file:

```
def create_new_user(new_user):
    print(new_user.first_name)
    assert new_user.first_name == "myfirstname"
```

However, the test didn't run and no error message was produced. I have the factory in my root inside the conftest.py file as mentioned in the documentation. I also have this settings in my pytest.ini file:
`python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_test.py`

What could have happened please?

Answer (score 6):

Name of the function should also comply with the conventions (`test_*`).